# Concatenate movie clips with differing fps?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

Suppose you have two .mp4 movie clips, with well-synched audio,

that you can view and listen to in any Web browser, in succession, 
even though their frame rate is different.

**Question:**   *What is the simplest way to concatenate those two into a single file?*

It seems that this should be such a frequent and desirable task
for anyone going from 3D modeling, to rendering, to animation, no?

E.g. suppose you are working on a scene intended for a brief animation,
where motion is slow enough in the first ten seconds
that you are satisfied with *half* of the basic 24 fps, but then comes 
four seconds of motion so fast and sweeping that you want *twice* that basic rate.
Suppose the rendering of each frame takes about a minute:
that means that the first ten seconds would take about two hours
from scene to image sequence, but the next four seconds 
would take over three hours.

After a lot of to and fro between modeling and rendering, 
you decide you want to show this to your peers:
you then make two movie clips (with 12 and 48 fps respectively),
add a sound track to each, and presto!

**All that’s missing now, is to concatenate those two into a single file.** 
How?

Note that we’re talking *same dimensions, same codec!*

Comment: You have to choose the side effect that you prefer. If the frame rates differ then there will be either duplication of frames to stretch the lower frame rate to the higher rate OR you will drop frames to get the high down to the low. Use the VSE speed effect strip to stretch one to the other.

Comment: Thank you!

But there really should be no side effect, since we don’t want to alter the movie clips in any way 

<i>except</i> to have them play in immediate succession, that’s all. 

My suspicion is that that needs to be achieved either with some clever Python code 

for Blender, or, with an external app like, ffmpeg ?

Comment: In fact, I just saw that ffmpeg (which is what Blender uses, internally)   
has a _concat_ command: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-concat-3   
which accepts different frame rates!    
(Of course, audio and video should be well synched in each file.)

Comment: Hmm, well let me know how differing playback rates with in one file goes. I know that screen captures can have variable frame rates but they typically require special codecs.